# Every surface of revolution is orientable

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, orientation

I understand this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3597999/691503) to my question. But what if I have the following definition of "orientable manifold"?

Let $M$ be a manifold of class $C^k$, where $1\leq k \leq +\infty$. An atlas $\mathcal{A}$ over $M$ is called coherent if the coordinate changes preserve the orientation of $\mathbb R^m$, that is, if $\mathrm{x}_\alpha,\mathrm{x}_\beta\in\mathcal A$, then $\mathrm{x}_\beta\circ\mathrm{x}_\alpha^{-1}$ has a positive Jacobian for every point of $\mathrm{x}_\alpha(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta)$. We will say that M is an orientable manifold if M admits a coherent atlas.

I know that every surface can be locally parameterized by $\varphi(u,v)=(f(v)\cos(u), f(v)\sin(u),g(v))$, where $0<u<2\pi$ and $a<v<b$, but how can I use the definition of an orientable manifold to prove that every surface of revolution is orientable? This is where I get a bit stuck...

Of course my idea is the following:
Let $x_1(u,v)=(f(v)\cos(u), f(v)\sin(u),g(v))$ defined in $U_1=\{(u,v):0<u<2\pi,a<v<b\}$ and $x_2(u,v)=(f(v)\cos(u), f(v)\sin(u),g(v))$ defined in $U_1=\{(u,v):-\pi<u<\pi,a<v<b\}$ these two parameterizations satisfy that $x_1(U_1)\cup x_2(U_2)=M$. So taking the cards $x_1^{-1}$ and $x_2^{-1}$ the following should be fulfilled, this is where I don't know how to attack it:

1. I am getting very complicated in calculating the inverse
2. I am getting complicated with the issue of order since I initially gave a parameterization but to do the accounts I need cards, therefore I am getting complicated with that.
3. For a moment I thought that the inverse could be $x_1^{-1}(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\arctan(y/x))$, but for example $x_1^{-1}\circ x_1$ is not the identity, at least I see it

Comment: Can you come up with two coordinates charts which covers the surface?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, thanks, I have tried to edit my question a bit, exposing my debts better, I think.

Comment: Is it not by definition that all normals are oriented either towards or away from.. the symmetry axis?

Comment: Of course that is true, but I would like to see how it is possible to prove that it is an orientable surface with this definition. I'm trying to see that this definition of orientability is compatible with the existence of a normal map of Gauss, so I want to do it with that definition.

Comment: Calculating chart inverses looks unnecessary: It suffices to see that on each component of the chart overlap, there exists an  integer $k$ such that $x_2^{-1}\circ x_1(u, v) = (u + 2\pi k, v)$.